# How can I digitally sign a PDF document quickly and cheaply?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, digital-signature

I need to digital sign a PDF document. However, Acrobat reader does not let me sign documents. I just need to sign the document, not edit it.

Do I need to buy the full Acrobat software?

Or is there a better, simpler way?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/858677/87699 for an up-do-date answer as of Dec 30, 2014

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options for digitally signing PDF files. You could use Acrobat Standard for this, but if all you want to do is to digitally sign PDF files then [Nitro PDF](http://www.nitropdf.com/) or [Foxit Phantom](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/phantom/) are more reasonably priced solutions (approx $99, cheaper if you find a special deal).

As far as free solutions go there is [Signature995](http://download.cnet.com/Signature995/3000-2092_4-10076830.html?tag=mncol;3), which is supported by ads, so be warned.

Answer (score 0):

On PC - I used to add my signatures using PDF X-Change view

On Mac - I'm now using PDF Signer from http://pdfsign.com ($10 on the mac store) to do it

Comment: The free version of PDF X-Change adds a "DEMO" watermark when signing documents. The PRO version is $37.50 - http://www.tracker-software.com/pdf-xchange-products-comparison-chart